# tengo un problema en eclipse con swing y JCalendar el apartado propiedades está vacío, alguien sabe ? gracias

Tags: java-swing, jcalendar

[image: Imagen de las propiedades vacías]

La sección de propiedades está vacía si alguien sabe, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Creo que debe ser un problema de la libreria de jcalendar que usas.

He hecho un refactor de jcalendar y le he agregado los cambios de las demas librerias variantes de jcalendar que pude hallar para maximizar la compatibilidad e integrar los diferentes enfoques.

Uno de los cambios que incluye es que he agregado los archivos `.form` que usa [matisse](/questions/tagged/matisse), y ya los he importado con exito en mis proyectos de netbeans usando la paleta de componentes de netbeans para importarlo.

Puedes hallar el codigo fuente en mi repositorio https://github.com/javatlacati/jcalendar

si usas maven puedes importarla mediante

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.javatlacati.jcalendar</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcalendar</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Si usas gradle mediante

```
implementation group: 'com.github.javatlacati.jcalendar', name: 'jcalendar', version: '1.3.4'
```

Si deseas la ultima version disponible en el repo puedes usar jitpack para obtenerla.

Si tras usar esta version sigues sin poderlo ver te sugiero agregar detalles de cmo estas agregando el componente a la paleta o al formulario